# Bootable USB Stick Failing To Load

Tags: windows, usb

After creating a bootable USB stick on my windows computer, I turned off a seperate computer, a laptop that I owned and plugged the USB stick into the computer. I turned it on and the splash screen for the manufacturer came up, in this case, Acer. I waited 5 minutes and nothing changed, <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> were unresponsive.

I turned off the computer, plugged the USB into my netbook and booted that up. Again, it froze on the manufacturer splash, in this case, HP.

When I plugged the USB back into my main computer, it is called "**Install Ubuntu (E:)**" and seemingly has all the required files on it. I booted both laptops back up after removing the USB stick and both computers rebooted Windows without issue.

Thanks!

Comment: USB booting is very iffy and to my knowledge there isn't an actual standard, especially on older computers.  Have you tried unetbootin? http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Just tried that, originally I used whatever was recommended by the Ubuntu website, but this yielded the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I used this one [Create a usb on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), I hope it helps, never had a problem.  Sounds like your grub got screwed up when you created the bootable usb. Let me know if it works for you.